# How to add compilers to heroku?

Tags: python-2.7, heroku

I have been working on a project that requires multiple compilers for the project to run. The project is similar to a online competitive coding website. It's written in python 2.7.12 using django framework. I want to add compilers like gcc, g++, clang, ruby, java, mono to my heroku cedar. I have very less experience in heroku deployment so any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to apply multiple [buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) to your app, some of which you may need to take from the vast choice of [Heroku Elements buildpacks](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks).
See also [Using Multiple Buildpacks for an App](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app).